# TLB in Intel chips

Tags: cpu, history

When did Intel chips start to have a translation lookaside buffer?

Comment: TLB was invented in 1964 by John Couleur while working for GE. Intel was founded in 1968, I wonder if it was used on the first processor under the Intel name, I emailed Intel about this question, maybe they can dig up the information.

Comment: Invention of TLB found in the References section of this PDF...http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~remzi/OSFEP/vm-tlbs.pdf

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Intel's email response to this question.

"When (Date) and which processor (model) did Intel first implement the Translation Lookaside Buffer (TLB)technology. "

> Thank you for contacting Intel® Customer Support.
>
> Although this channel is intended to support customers with actual active support hardware concerns during their integration or use, the TLB has being under use since the x86 processor architecture, which are all currently all End of Interactive Support (no longer supported by chat, phones nor email).
>
> For information on processor history and evolution you can review the following links.
>
> http://download.intel.com/pressroom/kits/IntelProcessorHistory.pdf
>
> http://www.intel.com/pressroom/kits/quickreffam.htm
>
> For more information on TLB you can review page 163:
>
> http://www.intel.com/Assets/PDF/manual/253668.pdf?wapkw=(translation+lookaside+buffer)